# force MVC OutputCache differ between ajax requests and normal requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, pagination, partial-views

I am using mvcPagedList for paging my index action. Inside index action I return a partial view for ajax requests and whole view for normal requests.

```
 return Request.IsAjaxRequest()
            ? (ActionResult)PartialView("_index", listPaged)
            : View(listPaged);
```

But for caching I have problem because it won't detect if the request is ajax or not and instead of returning a partial view I get the whole view or reverse. It depends the first request is ajax or not!

I tried adding VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With" to OutputCache attribute but no luck.
Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786690/asp-net-outputcache-varybyparam-and-varybyheader-with-ajax?rq=1) might be handy.

Comment: I have seen that post already. but I have this code:
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "long", VaryByParam="*", VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]

Comment: I changed it to this line of code and now it works. but anyone knows how to this with donut caching?

[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "long", Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "*", VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]